# Como usar method_exist()

Tags: php

Bom pessoal, quero usar o `method_exist()`, estou tentando passar valores para minha classe em `PHP`, na `URL` que preciso chamar a classe é necessário chamar o método para onde os valores vão.

Como fica um arquivo para cuidar disso ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem a pergunta, mas aqui vai o que é a função e como usa-la.

A função [method_exists()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.method-exists.php) apenas verifica se um método existe:

**Descrição:**

```
bool method_exists ( object $object , string $method_name )
```

- Retorna **bool** (`true` se o método foi encontrado e `false` se não);
- Recebe um **object** (no caso seria sua classe);
- Também recebe uma **string** (com o nome do método);

**Definição:**

```
if(method_exists('MinhaClasse','MeuMetodo')) {
    echo "existe";
} else {
    echo "não existe";
}
```

---

**Exemplo**:

```
<?php
    $directory = new Directory('.');
    var_dump(method_exists($directory,'read')); //retorna true pois existe o método read na classe de diretório
?>
```

o mesmo pode ver feito assim:

```
<?php
    var_dump(method_exists('Directory','read'));
?>
```

---

**Exemplo:**

```
<?php
    class A {
        public function FUNC() {
            echo '*****'; 
        }
    }

    $a = new A();
    $a->func(); // printa *****
    var_dump(method_exists($a, 'func')); // retorna bool(true) pois existe tal método
?>
```

---

Veja mais: [Documentação do PHP: method_exists()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.method-exists.php)

Comment: Obrigado por esse resumo, ajudou muito !